# Visual Studio 2013 Hide Notification Button

Tags: visual-studio, button, notifications, hide, visual-studio-2013

I have a question about Visual Studio 2013.
I just installed it and it seems pretty good because of the new features.

But there is something I do not like:

[image]

Is it possible somehow removing these 3 x buttons ? Or just one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment the social features don't seem to have any corresponding options you can use to disable them.

There is a method that relies on using [Visual Commander](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to repeatedly hide some of the buttons (as Visual Studio 
often recreates them), which seems like the closest you'll get for the moment.

http://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2013/10/19/hide-sign-in-and-feedback-buttons-in-the-visual-studio-2013-main-window/ - You can view the code in the "Extensions" section.

Unless you're desparate to get rid of them, you're probably better of trying to ignore them, hopefully an option to hide them will become available.

Answer (score 35):

Yes you can hide them.

Close Visual Studio.
Open regedit and find MainWindowFrameControls.

For example I want to remove:
1) Sign In
2) Notifications

So I need to delete:
{304ee989-b7c9-46c8-aa48-f080bc47cee0}
{73988e61-7e30-4e87-b891-23b5e460db21}

You can also delete them and it will work (you can remove feedback also by this way).
Although sometime VS recreates that keys. But solution is very easy - instead of deleting make right click and go to Permissions, add Everyone - Deny - Read. So now nobody will be able to read that keys including VS.
You can remove it to go to original state by the same way.

Comment: I did this and was initially successful - but at some time afterwards - everything came back! And what's with putting this stuff in the registry anyway? - IMO apps should be self-contained. Terrible design decision

Comment: Maybe VS can now restore permissions. Or you are logged under different account. In 1st case you can remove all permissions and set owner "SYSTEM" for corresponding key. In 2nd - you need to set permissions for corresponding account.

Comment: Thanks. I've only ever used the same account, but I'll have a look at the permissions, and keep an eye them.

Comment: Can confirm now, that somehow VS 2013 restores these deleted registry entries. Grrr... Can't believe we give Microsoft good money just to let them irritate us like this. Will try your permissions workaround instead.

Comment: I just managed to remove them. There are multiple instances of the key. I set deny permissions on the MainWindowFrameControls key for all of them. Had to fiddle with regedit under the system account to finally get rid of those annoying icons :)

Comment: Just noticed they're back. I guess locking down the key permissions only works temporarily. My next attempt is to change the ViewId value, in each of the subkeys, from 0x64 to 0x63, and now they're gone again :)

Comment: Aaaannnd they're all back again. Will try @GravityWell's ViewId suggestion

Comment: Last time I got some strange thing. VS created alternative path 12.0_ConfigXXXX, where XXXX is some number (it was after installation of some extensions for VS). And my attempts to change (deny) anything in 12.0_Config key was not successful. So I removed both config keys... After that VS recreated original config key and I got exactly what I desired by changing permissions (deny on read).

Comment: Best solution! If the buttons are added back after a while simply run `REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\MainWindowFrameControls\{F66FBC48-9AE4-41DC-B1AF-0D64F0F54A07}` etc from the commandline or add this to a batch job that is executed during startup.

Comment: You can find the `MainWindowFrameControls` key at `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\##.#_Config(_####)\MainWindowFrameControls]`, where `##.#` is a version number (e.g. `12.0`) and the `(_####)` is some other number Microsoft may append to the key (e.g. `_1840`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Disable Social Features](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9d53c284-25ec-454c-acad-ae68ecf5b1d5) extension, which will programmatically hide both the 'smiley' buttons as well as your own name/photo from the front of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Drew I think his original answer (and the current version of it) are both fine. The extension appears to do exactly what OP asked for. Why do you think it is of "very low quality"?

Comment: @Zero3 gotcha. Thanks. Btw, rev1 needs a facelift.